# How to get a facebook user's friends emails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good Evening, i'm just asking how to get a user's friends emails using face book API or something else, the scenario i want to use this feature in goes as follows, my application has a feature called 'import facebook friends' that will do the following:
- verifies that this user has a valid facebook account
- asks him for his facebook identifier(email)
- from his identifier get all his friends and get everyone's email
i don't know if there's any API that performs this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a user's email address, you need the `user_email` permission. However, there is no equivalent `friends_email` permission to get Friends' email addresses as Facebook doesn't allow applications to get these.

Instead, you the Facebook User ID to link friends together. That is the correct way to do things, since the email address can change anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can get almost all details about friends like their photos,interests, status updates but not `email address`.

From Facebook [Email Permission Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) : "Note: There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends."